# scipy ode update set_f_params inside function set as set_solout

Tags: python, scipy, ode, scientific-computing

When integrating an ode with scipy, ode accepts a function with more arguments than t and y. For example:

`def fun(t, y, param1, param2):`

and the value of these arguments can be set using `set_f_params` method.

However, when using also `set_solout` method and trying to update the params with `set_f_params` inside this function, the integration remains the same as if the params were not being modified.

How would you modify the the params using sol_out? **I would like to benefit from dopri5 dense output**, but I need the non-homogeneous terms to be updated at every time step.

A minimal example is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode

def fun(t, x, param):
    return x - param

def f_param(t):
    return t

ode1 = ode(fun).set_integrator('dopri5').set_initial_value([10.0])
ode1.set_f_params(f_param(0))
results1 = ([], [])

ode2 = ode(fun).set_integrator('dopri5').set_initial_value([10.0])
ode2.set_f_params(f_param(0))
results2 = ([], [])

def callback1(t, x):
    results1[0].append(t)
    results1[1].append(x.copy())

def callback2(t, x):
    results2[0].append(t)
    results2[1].append(x.copy())
    ode2.set_f_params(f_param(t))

ode1.set_solout(callback1)
ode2.set_solout(callback2)

ode1.integrate(3)
ode2.integrate(3)

plt.plot(results1[0], results1[1], 'o-', alpha=0.7, label='ode1')
plt.plot(results2[0], results2[1], '.--', label='ode2')
plt.legend()
```

and the results are shown here:

[image]

Comment: Note that you most likely can circumvent this problem by not using parameters at all but doing whatever you need to do to obtain the time-dependent parameters when computing the derivative. In your example, you could just do with `def fun(t, x): return x - f_param(t)`. As its name suggests, `set_solout` is if you want something like an output after every adaptive integration step. Also note that every integration step contains multiple function evaluations at different times. Thus, using `set_solout` is changing your parameters less often than the alternative I suggested.

Comment: You are right, using `set_solout` to update params is not the best alternative since they will be fixed for the adaptive integration step. However, calling directly to the function that sets the params inside the function you want to integrate is not always an option. Nevertheless, that function could be passed as the param itself and would never need to be updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how one would do it with [the new ODE solvers](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) to be released in SciPy 1.0:

```
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def fun_fixed(t, x, param):
    return x - param

sol_fixed = solve_ivp(
    partial(fun_fixed, param=0), (0, 3), [10.0], dense_output=True)

def fun_param(t, x, fun):
    return -x + fun(t)

def f_param(t):
    return t

sol_param = solve_ivp(
    partial(fun_param, fun=f_param), (0, 3), [10.0], dense_output=True)

t = np.linspace(0, 3, num=16)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.plot(t, sol_fixed.sol(t)[0], 'o-', alpha=0.7, label='ode1')
plt.plot(t, sol_param.sol(t)[0], 's-.', label='ode3')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Two solutions]

Comment: Much easier and functional! Great! Thanks @astrojuanlu

Comment: @astrojuanlu is it possible to use this solver for a system of ode?

Comment: Of course, and also the older solvers. You have to write them in vector/array form, check out the documentation.

Comment: What is fun(t) ?

Comment: Is this not slightly superfluous? Can one not include the code of f_param in fun_param itself?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the comment of @Wrzlprmft, it is safer not to use params if they are not constant and calling the function that updates the params directly in the function you want to update. As he says, that means:

```
def fun(t, x):
    return x - f_param(t)
```

However, that function (`f_param` in this case) may not be accessible in the namespace of the function to be integrated (`fun` in the example above). Thus, it is more convenient to set the function as an argument to the function to be integrated and use `set_f_params` just once at the beginning to specify the function.

As a continuation of the code in the question:

```
def fun3(t, x, fun):
return -x + fun(t)

def fun4(t, x):
    return -x + t 

ode3 = ode(fun3).set_integrator('dopri5').set_initial_value([10.0])
ode3.set_f_params(f_param)
results3 = ([], [])

ode4 = ode(fun4).set_integrator('dopri5').set_initial_value([10.0])
results4 = ([], [])

def callback3(t, x):
    results3[0].append(t)
    results3[1].append(x.copy())

def callback4(t, x):
    results4[0].append(t)
    results4[1].append(x.copy())

ode3.set_solout(callback3)
ode4.set_solout(callback4)

ode3.integrate(3)
ode4.integrate(3)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.plot(results1[0], results1[1], 'o-', alpha=0.7, label='ode1')
plt.plot(results2[0], results2[1], '.--', label='ode2')
plt.plot(results3[0], results3[1], 's-.', label='ode3')
plt.plot(results4[0], results4[1], '^-.', label='ode3')
plt.legend()
```

Is shown that ode3 and ode4 provide the same solution:

[image: solutions]