# Does scipy's solve_ivp have a similar method to ode's set_f_params?

Tags: python, scipy, integrator

For scipy's ode method there exists the set_f_params function to update any args provided: [Use solve_ivp with varying parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262350/use-solve-ivp-with-varying-parameters?rq=3). This is something I'm looking for with the solve_ivp method, but have been unable to find reproduce, does anyone know how to do so?

Essentially, I am propagating a state vector y, and I want to calculate a change in additional args I supply to solve_ivp, I then want to basically supply these changed args again to solve_ivp. For anyone interested, it refers to the propagation of two natural satellites and I want to update the gravity field coefficients during the propagation, but I am having quite a hard time doing so.

To be more specific, the exact set of equations I am trying to implement is as follows:

[Set of coupled differential equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5vUu.png)

I can implement Eq. 5.20, 5.21 and the second equation of 5.22 fine in the state y. I can then call solve_ivp and it will simply return me the solution. What I fail to understand however, is how, based on the resulting $\Delta Z^\nu {l,m}$ for each integration step, I can update $\Delta Z{l,m}$ accordingly using the left equation in 5.22. This new delta $Z_{l,m}$ will be used in the right hand side of equations 5.20 and 5.21, and hence it's important that I do all of this concurrently.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Do the gravity coefficients depend on `t` or `y`? If so, why not define them in the callable `fun`? If not, what do they depend on?

Comment: The gravity field coefficients indeed depend on y and t, but y also depends on the gravity field coefficients to be calculated. So essentially I start with a set value for them, calculate what y will be at my next time step, and from this new y I calculate the change in gravity field coefficients and then update them as well. My main issue is that I thus supply these coefficients as input parameters to the callable function, but I also must update them for each step the integrator takes

Comment: Ok, then how is this different from making them part of the state `y`, rather than specified as parameters?

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully make it more clearer.

Comment: The integrator doesn't takes all steps of equal duration. You've said that you want to update the parameter with each time step, but that would mean that the solution depends on the integrator's choice of time step. That can't be right, so do you really mean you want to update after every fixed time interval of a specified duration? (That is, update it on a fixed schedule?)

Comment: For updating the parameter on a fixed schedule, there is no method like `set_f_params` with `solve_ivp`. You would just call `solve_ivp` again with the new initial state being the old final state and the new parameters updated as desired. This can be done in a loop that pauses integration at certain times when the parameter needs to be updated and/or when certain events occur in the state. If that is what you're looking for, I can demonstrate in an answer.

Comment: No, sorry, I should've been clearer on that part; I agree that it should be done for every integration step, where the step sizes themselves can be variable, that's totally fine (though in practice for these 'simple' cases a fixed step-size integrator and variable step-size integrator perform quite similar). I assume that this would follow the same (or easier) method you described in your last comment, is that correct? If so, I would love to see a demonstration of that, especially the point where I would call solve_ivp again with a new set of args

Comment: I can do that, but it's just hard to understand physically why that is ok. Rarely do the laws of nature care how we plan to simulate them! It sounds to me like the underlying physics change continuously with time, and changing these parameters in discrete time is only an approximation that assumes something about the steps the solver takes. But yes, I'll write a demo in a few hours.

Comment: What you said yesterday didn't initially strike a bell with me, but you're absolutely right. I don't know how I oversaw that, but it obviously does not make sense to update these parameters every time an integration step is taken... If my integrator is taking really small step sizes, it will update it far too often which of course is not physically accurate. I was trying to solve the wrong problem here, and I think I know how to move forward now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please consider writing an answer if one that is posted is not what you're looking for. Stack Overflow is about posting questions and answers so others can find help with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I went about it the wrong way. The gravity field coefficients should not be updated every integration step. Since it does not explicitly depend on time, the first equation in 5.22 might be of similar magnitude regardless of the step size my variable step size integrator takes, thus producing a result that is not physically accurate.

As of right now, it seems that overwriting the gravity field coefficients at every integration step with its constant value and this added pertubation does the trick in providing a physically realistic solution. Hence, there is no need for me to figure out how to vary the input args of the `solve_ivp` function.